# io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not initialize the Realm Object Server

Tags: android, realm

I tried to send an object through intents to do this I have modified my data class from

```
open class Stream : RealmObject() {

@PrimaryKey
lateinit var id : String
lateinit var detail : String
lateinit var name : String
lateinit var url:String
```

}

to

```
open class Stream : RealmObject(), Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
lateinit var id : String
lateinit var detail : String
lateinit var name : String
lateinit var url:String
```

}

if the class implements Serializable we can make use of putSerializableExtra and getSerializableExtra and now I have problem with Realm initialization

This is my Stack trace `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.vinaysaripella.funfacts, PID: 7202
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.vinaysaripella.funfacts.ServiceModule: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not initialize the Realm Object Server`

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not initialize the Realm Object Server
                  at io.realm.internal.SyncObjectServerFacade.init(SyncObjectServerFacade.java:60)
                  at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:249)
                  at com.example.vinaysaripella.funfacts.ServiceModule.onCreate(ServiceModule.kt:24)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740)
```

Comment: I don't think the two things are related, so you might want to include the stack trace.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I edited my question and added a part of stack trace.

Comment: Is there really no any additional error message beyond that?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Sorry I update the post.

Comment: Do you by any chance have `multiDexEnabled true`? Do you have Proguard enabled in this build? There's even a chance that a clean+rebuild would fix it although that would be a surprise.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes multiDexEnabled is true and Proguard is enabled and I tried clean+rebuild but I have the same exception.

Comment: If multiDex is enabled, then do you `extends MultiDexApplication` in your custom application? you should

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes I extend MultiDexApplication in my custom application.

Comment: In that case try a Proguard configuration `-keep class io.realm.ObjectServer`